# NativeScript: TabView icons on Android are too small

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

In android, I can't seem to make my TabViewItem icon sizes larger.  I tried adding an explicit height and width in the XML but that doesn't change anything.   Right now, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl9by.jpg which is too small for me.  I also tried giving it a class and changing via CSS but still no luck .  My code is as follows:

```
<TabViewItem :title='`FAVORITES ${this.favorites && this.favorites.length ? this.favorites.length : ""}`' width="60" height="60" iconSource="~/assets/images/heart-Icon.png">
    <Frame
        id="favorites-list-frame"
        row="0"
    >
        <CustomComponent/>
        
    </Frame>
</TabViewItem>
```

Any way to make these larger?